# JQuery scrollTop speed strange behavior depending of direction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe, whose content should be scrolled up and down by onmuseover on one of two image buttons. Here is a part of HTML code:

```
    <!-- News -->
    <table class="HomeITable" border="0px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="182px" height="246px">
     <tr>
      <td class="HomeITableHead" align="left" valign="top" width="182px" height="23px"><a href="cgi-bin/d4_adm_news.cgi" target="_top"><img src="images/home_table_head_news.png" border="0" alt="" width="182px" height="23px" style="border: 0px solid #FFFFFF" /></a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" width="182px" height="11px" style="width: 182px; height: 11px"><img id="ScrollNewsUp" src="images/home_table_button_up_pas.png" border="0" alt="" width="182px" height="11px" style="border: 0px solid #FFFFFF" onmouseover="HomeTableScroll(this,'news','up')" onmouseout="StopHomeTableScroll(this,'news')" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" width="182px" height="198px" style="width: 182px; height: 198px">
          <iframe id="IFnews" src="frames/news.html" width="172px" height="190px" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" style="width: 172px; height: 190px; visibility: visible"></iframe>
      </td> 
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" width="182px" height="11px" style="width: 182px; height: 11px"><img id="ScrollNewsDn" src="images/home_table_button_down_pas.png" border="0" alt="" width="182px" height="11px" style="border: 0px solid #FFFFFF" onmouseover="HomeTableScroll(this,'news','down')" onmouseout="StopHomeTableScroll(this,'news')" /></td> 
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" width="182px" height="3px" style="width: 182px; height: 3px"></td> 
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Here are javascript functions:

```
// home tables scroll

var HTScrollTime=10000;

function HomeTableScroll(CalObj,CItable,Cdirect){

    var frameWindow=$('#IF'+CItable).get(0).contentWindow;

    var scrollToValue=0;
    if(Cdirect=='down'){scrollToValue=frameWindow.$(document).height();}

    if(CalObj.src){
        CalObj.src=CalObj.src.toString().replace("_pas.png","_act.png");
        frameWindow.$("html, body").animate({scrollTop : scrollToValue},HTScrollTime);
    }
}

function StopHomeTableScroll(CalObj,CItable){

    var frameWindow=$('#IF'+CItable).get(0).contentWindow;

    if(CalObj.src){
        CalObj.src=CalObj.src.toString().replace("_act.png","_pas.png");
        frameWindow.$("html, body").stop(true,false);
    }
}
```

As is apparent from the above code, the scrolling time is set to 10000 mS (10 seconds)

The strange thing is that when you scroll down (by onmouseover on lower "button") scrolling takes five seconds, and when you scroll up (by onmouseover on upper "button") scrolling takes 10 seconds.

I can not understand why scrolling down is twice faster than the set.

I would appreciate any idea.

The whole thing can be seen here: http://lyaskovets.bydimo.com/index1.php 
It comes to the first two orange tables (*Новини* and *Обяви*).

Comment: I am not sure why this is happening, but maybe you could check if Cdirect == 'up' and if it does use HTScrollTime/2

Comment: @VincentFaller Thank you. Yes, I have an idea how to go round the problem, but more interesting is why it occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

*frameWindow.$(document).height()* **doesn't return** the height of the document in the iframe. It returns the usable height of whole browser window, i.e. it depends on the size of the window.

In my case real height of the document in iframe is 516px, but (in my screen resolution) the browser window usable height is 1138px, which is approximately twice more. And because it is obtained a double speed difference

If I get the height of the document in iframe using javascript: ***frameWindow.document.body.scrollHeight***, it returns the correct heightof 516px and everything is ok.

```
function HomeTableScroll(CalObj,CItable,Cdirect){

    var frameWindow=$('#IF'+CItable).get(0).contentWindow;

    var scrollToValue=0;
    //if(Cdirect=='down'){scrollToValue=frameWindow.$(document).height();}
    if(Cdirect=='down'){scrollToValue=frameWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;}

    if(CalObj.src){
        CalObj.src=CalObj.src.toString().replace("_pas.png","_act.png");
        frameWindow.$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: scrollToValue}, {duration: HTScrollTime, easing: "linear"});
    }
}
```